# Multiple monitors on UltraVNC

Tags: windows-7, vnc, vncserver, ultravnc

I have UltraVNC installed as a silent service. I now have a dual monitor setup and want UltraVNC to use my secondary monitor instead of the old primary one. I'm running Windows 7.

I use the HTTP Java client to view my VNC. (`localhost:5800`)

I went to the settings app in the UltraVNC directory and ticked the "Secondary monitor" checkbox. However the HTTP Java client still shows my primary monitor.

Additionally, when I move my mouse over to this extended secondary monitor, the Java client gives an error:

> Error: Framebuffer update rectangle too large 0x0 at ...

Why isn't it showing the secondary monitor in the first place?

Comment: a side note: I was unsuccessful in finding *ANY* application/software/trick for broadcasting multiple monitors on windows.. UltraVNC had the option, but it isnt working..